# Как работают битовые операции в данных программах?

Tags: c++, c, битовые-операции

```
unsigned char i = 0, j(50), k = 128;
for(i = 17; i < 33; i += 3){
    j += k++;
    k >>= 1;
}
printf("i = %03d; j = %d; k = %04d", i, j, k);
return 44;
```

...

```
unsigned char d, f, g;
int a = 520;
d = a++;
f = --d;
g = d & 0x7E;
g <<= 3;
printf("d = %d; f = %d; g = %d", d, f++, g);
```

Расскажите как работают сдвиги в данных программах.

P.S.буду очень благодарен, если что это две разные программы

Comment: Как написано. Сдвигает биты значения на указанное количество в указанном направлении. Если непонятно — считайте, что это умножение/деление. `k >>= 1;` — `k /= 2;`. `g <<= 3` — `g *= 8`.

Comment: Harry, не стоит  битовые сдвиги рассматривать так,  не то  представлять станет трудней что к чему...

Comment: @wafelek, В данной программе?... битовые операции во всех программах работают одинаково.

Comment: Конвертируешь в двоичный формат и сдигаешь бит по направлению, потом переводишь обратно в десятичный формат

Comment: @ARHovsepyan: "в данных программах" я не имел ввиду, что битовые операции в разных программах работают по разному, просто написал в таком смысле.

Comment: Переместите в первой программе printf внутрь цикла, замените в нем %d на %x, запустите программу  и внимательно рассмотрите вывод

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Труднее. Но, судя по вопросу, ТС не ищет легких путей :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перевод числа в 2 двоичную систему счисления и побитовый сдвиг.
Рассмотрим на примере k >>= 1;
Пусть К = 10 переводим в 2ю систему счислений 1010
далее выполняем сдвиг и получаем 101 что будет 5

То есть действие >> убирает справа цифру в двоичном числе

А << добавляет 0 справа